# How to encode SecKey to base64 string using swift

Tags: swift, rsa

I want to encode keys to base64 string. But i really can't understand how to do it. I tried to find some information but i find nothing. Thats why im asking for help here. I will be very grateful for any help.
 For now i have this:

```
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    var statusCode: OSStatus = 0
    var publicKey: SecKey?
    var privateKey: SecKey?

    let publicKeyAttribute: [NSObject : NSObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent: true as NSObject, kSecAttrApplicationTag: "dove.apppublic".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject]

    let privateKeyAtrribute: [NSObject: NSObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent: true as NSObject, kSecAttrApplicationTag: "dove.appprivate".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject]

    var keyPairAttr = [NSObject: Any]()
```

and
 func keysGeneration() {

```
    rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecAttrType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
    rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits] = 2048
    rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecReturnData] = true
    rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecPublicKeyAttrs] = rsaKeyGenerator.publicKeyAttribute
    rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecPrivateKeyAttrs] = rsaKeyGenerator.privateKeyAtrribute


    rsaKeyGenerator.statusCode = SecKeyGeneratePair(rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &rsaKeyGenerator.publicKey, &rsaKeyGenerator.privateKey)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let publicKey = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(rsaKeyGenerator.publicKey!, &rsaKeyGenerator.error)
        let privateKey = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(rsaKeyGenerator.privateKey!, &rsaKeyGenerator.error)
//            print("MY PUBLIC KEY = \(publicKey)")
//            print("MY PRIVATE KEY = \(privateKey)")

    }
```

Comment: The first thing is wrong: `rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecAttrType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA`. It should be `rsaKeyGenerator.keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeyType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a string to its base64 representation, you need to take a trip through `Data`.

```
let s = "string to encode as base64"
let d = s.data(using: .utf8)
let b64 = base64EncodedString()
```